# Can this equation be balanced using ion-electron method?

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox, combustion

Reaction:

$\ce{C2H4 + O2 → CO2 + H2O}$

I want to balance the above reaction using the ion-electron method.

My attempt:

Ox-half: $\ce{C2^(^-^2^)H4 + 4H2O → 2C^(^+^4^)O2 + 12H^+ +12e^-}$

Red-half: $\ce{2O2^(^0^) + 4H^+ + 8e^-→ CO2^(^-^2^) + 2H2O^(^-^2^)}$

After making the electrons gained and lost equal and adding them, and finally summing up, the carbon atoms and the oxygen atoms get unbalanced. How is it supposed to be balanced?

Comment: Your red-half itself is not balanced. All in all, this method is hardly ever used in organic chemistry, though still technically applicable.

Comment: @IvanNeretin How would we balance it then?

Comment: The way kids do. How did you balance reactions before you ever heard of the ion-electron method?

Comment: Yeah, but I wish to use this approach.

Comment: It feels pretty much like chopping trees with a shovel, but if you insist...
$$\ce{C^{(-2)}2H4 -> 2C^{(+4)} + 4H+ + 12e- }\\
\ce{O2 + 4e- -> 2O^{(-2)}}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can all equations be balanced using ion-electron method?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/176268/can-all-equations-be-balanced-using-ion-electron-method)

Comment: Asking again about the same thing isn't a good idea...

Comment: @AyushNaman - I'm definitely old school, but what you calling the *ion-electron method* is known to me as an *oxidation-reduction reaction.*

Answer (score 0):

The reduction half equation starts from $\ce{O2}$ and goes to $\ce{H2O}$, with the help of $\ce{H+}$. So it is something like $$\ce{O2 + .. H+ + .. e- -> 2 H2O}$$As $\ce{2 H2O}$ contains $4$ $ \ce{H}$ atoms, these atoms must be provided at left by $4$ $\ce{H+}$ ions, and, as a consequence by $4$ electrons. This makes the final reduction half-equation $$\ce{O2 + 4 H+ + 4 e- -> 2 H2O}$$ There is no carbon atom here.